# Exists a strictly increasing $\mathbb{N}$-valued $(a_n)_{n}$ s. th. $\sum_n n/a_n< \infty$ and $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k/k}{n^2}\to c\in (0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I think, that I already know, that $n/a_n$ can not be monotone, since if it is increasing the first sum will be $\infty$, since $a_n>0$.
And if it is decreasing the summability condition does imply $\frac{n^2}{a_n}\to 0$ i.e. $a_n = n^2\cdot b_n$ with $b_n \to \infty$. Now let $T\in \mathbb{N}$. Then there is a $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n\ge T$ for all $n\ge n_0$. But this does imply that for $n\ge n_0$ we have

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n_0}\frac{a_k}{k}+\sum_{k=n_0+1}^n k\cdot b_k \ge C+T\sum_{k= n_0+1}^n k = C+T\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}-\frac{n_0^2+n_0}{2}\right)  $
which does imply 
$\liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k}}{n^2}\ge \liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{2C+T(n^2+n-n_0^2-n_0)}{2n^2} = \frac{T}{2}.$ And since this does hold for all $T\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k}}{n^2} = \infty$. (This argument may be flawed and if it is, I would be grateful if it is pointed out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we have such a sequence. Let $N$ be such that $\sum_{n > N}{\frac{n}{a_n}} \leq \frac{1}{2c}$.

Then, for any $T > N$, by AM-HM,

$$\sum_{T \geq n > N}{\frac{n}{a_n}}\frac{1}{(T-N)^2}\sum_{T \geq n > N}{\frac{a_n}{n}}\geq 1.$$

In particular, $$\frac{1}{(T-N)^2}\sum_{T \geq n > N}{\frac{a_n}{n}}\geq 2c.$$

Now make $T \rightarrow \infty$ and we get a contradiction.

Note that we just needed $a_n >0$ to derive the contradiction and nothing else.